# Java EE Security Concept

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, active-directory, jacc

I need to create an application with `authentication` and `authorization` using Java EE 6 (Glassfish Server). I read a lot about Java EE 6 security and just wanted to ask if my concept is correct:

Every user in the company has an account according to `"X123456"`. I want to use this for `LDAP Authentication`:

Application ---> LDAP

So, I can use the company's infrastructure to authorize the user.

However I want to be in control of the roles in my application. So, I want to define my own roles using `JACC`. Therefore I will create a database with a user-to-role mapping,

`Example`: "X123456 -> ADMIN".

The benefits would be:

- I don't need to store any password
- I can create a kind of admin panel in my application where I can set the existing roles to users dynamically

Do you think this would be technically possible and good practice?

Alternative: Would it be possible to define the roles (Admin, User) in Active Directory and query it via LDAP? So I could outsource my user-to-role mapping into active directory.

Update:

- For authentication I currently use a LDAP-Realm (user, password).
- For authorization I want to use a database (rolename, user). However I don't know how to tell my application to use the database for authorization. If I would use a JDBC-Realm, I could specify the Group/Role table and column. Is there a way to tell my application to just use the JDBC-Realm for authorization?

Comment: Yes, and I guess it is quite common to have such an infrastructure. You will find a solution for Tomcat here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138450/implement-a-tomcat-realm-with-ldap-authentication-and-jdbc-authorization/26825690#26825690 Maybe you are able to transfer the main idea to GF